# Make an installer from a console application

Tags: c#, console-application, exe

I have a console application on Visual Studio 2012 C#. I need to put the .exe file and the config file in another computer to make it run everyday. When I copy the files and I execute it, it works fine. When I execute it again the next day to make sure that the application works, it doesn't work, it crashes.

I tried to publish the application but the publish doesn't even work locally when I install it.
Is there any solution or what I could copy or generate to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Installers don't do anything special, they just copy the necessary `.exe`, `.dll`, etc. files to their location, and perhaps check for pre-requisites, all of which you can do manually. If it's working on Day 1 and crashing on Day 2, I'd assume your program either changes one of its own files after it runs, or you have a bug that's crashing it.

Comment: If it works one day and not the other, the problem is in your code. The Application log in the Event Log of the machine will tell you why the application cr**a**shed.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answers. I found out that it was crashing because there's a security feature blocking my application the next day. I spoke with the IT admin and the problem is solved now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thanks for the answers. I found out that it was crashing because there's a security feature blocking my application the next day. I spoke with the IT admin and the problem is solved now. Thanks a lot!